# What does с каре mean?

Tags: сленг

I have encountered девочка с каре in a [song](https://soundcloud.com/mukkaaa/mukka-devochka-s-kare-piano) and девушка с каре in comments on social media.  I have absolutely no idea what с каре means. Clarification would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/каре

Comment: Sometimes a simple image search goes a long way in solving these mysteries 

Comment: @CocoPop I did it, and was left with the impression that it meant "with hair"

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo 

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo And if you go the Spanish route, it sounds like she had a cavity 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're referring to a girl **[with a bob](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5&sca_esv=bf62f88ac657483c&sxsrf=AM9HkKlMMyla4H_oTjUY9ywh8omgf84uYQ%3A1699195858146&source=hp&ei=0qtHZf3CBo6GwbkPsfOAOA&iflsig=AO6bgOgAAAAAZUe54p9EL7jgyxlOO3iWns69znG1Q4c0&ved=0ahUKEwj985rsja2CAxUOQzABHbE5AAcQ4dUDCAs&uact=5&oq=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6GgIYAiIa0LTQtdCy0YPRiNC60LAg0YEg0LrQsNGA0LUyBRAAGIAEMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB4yCBAAGBYYHhgKMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB5I9iZQAFjnI3ACeACQAQCYAY0BoAG_DaoBBDUuMTG4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgwQIxiKBRgTGIAEGCfCAgQQIxgnwgILEAAYgAQYsQMYgwHCAgsQABiKBRixAxiDAcICCxAuGIAEGLEDGIMBwgIFEC4YgATCAgQQABgDwgIIEC4YgAQY1ALCAggQLhjUAhiABMICCxAuGIAEGMcBGK8B&sclient=gws-wiz)** ((hair)cut).

https://www.songtell.com/mukka/girl-with-a-bob-cut